# better format than using try and except

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

I am currently making a program that allows me to search for files in a user specified directory. But am having some trouble condensing down my `try` and `except` statements. My current code is as follows:

```
if os.path.exists(file_path)!= True:
        print('\n******* Path does not exist. *******\n')       

    else:
        while True:
            aa = '''\nWhich search characteristics would you like to use? \n 1. Search by name: N \n 2. Search by extension: E \n 3. Search by size: S
                \n    Please enter your choice: '''

            answer = input(aa).strip()

            if answer not in 'NnEeSs' or answer=='':
                print('\n***** Invalid choice. *****')

            elif answer in 'Nn':
                while True:
                    try:
                        name = input ('\nEnter file name: ')
                        rr = search_by_name(name, file_path)
                        if not rr:
                            print('\n***** File not found *****\n')
                        else:
                            break

                    except WindowsError:
                        print('\n***** Oops! Access denied.*****\n')
                        continue


            elif answer in 'Ee':
                while True:
                    try:
                        ending = input ('\nEnter the file extension: ')
                        rr = search_by_extention(ending, file_path)
                        if not rr:
                            print('\n***** No File(s) found *****\n')
                        else:
                            break

                    except WindowsError:
                        print('\n***** Oops! Access denied. *****\n')
                        continue              

            elif answer in 'Ss':
                while True:
                    try:
                        size = int(input('\nPlease enter file size: '))
                        rr = search_by_size(size, file_path)
                        if not rr:
                            print('\n***** No file(s) found *****\n')
                        else:
                            break

                    except ValueError:
                        print('\n***** Enter an numeric value. *****\n')
                        continue

                    except WindowsError:
                        print('\n***** Oops! Access denied. *****\n')
                        continue
```

In each of these cases or overall, is there a better condensed way to write the above code? Each of the search functions return a list containing the result of the code.

Comment: Belongs on the codereview site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions:

## 1. Improve indenting.

At the top of your file you have:

```
if os.path.exists(file_path)!= True:
    print('\n******* Path does not exist. *******\n')       

    else:
```

The `else` statement has to have the same indentation value as the original `if`.

## 2. Remove newlines

As you are concerned about taking space up, just remove all the newlines. I would not suggest this because your code can become confusing to read, but if you are a stickler about space, go ahead. I can count 11 newlines, so if you remove those, you've removed **<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>5</sub><sup>th</sup>** of your file.

## 3. Be pythonic

If you care about the *lines* your code is taking up, try to be as pythonic about each line as possible, for future review/editing. Instead of `if x in 'Ss':` to check if `x` is an `s` or `S`, just do `if x.lower() == 's':`

## 4. Format `try... except`

Your `try... except`'s encompass most of your code. Try to only limit them to the line that may raise the error. Here's an example:

```
try:
    var = int(raw_input())
    x = float(var)/100.0
    if x == 1:
        print 'YAY'
    else:
        print 'BOO!'
    for k in range(1, x):
        print 'this has looped %d times' %(k)
except ValueError:
    print 'Your input is not in a number format!'
```

In this code, we want to make sure that the input is a number. However, that can only be checked by the first line, and everything else is rubbish. So just surround the first line, and leave the rest untouched.

### Note:

**Do not remove necessary components from your `try... except`'s, or some arbitrary error may be raised.**

## 5. Shrink your `while` loops

Instead of doing the following code:

```
while True:
    try:
        size = int(input('\nPlease enter file size: '))
        rr = search_by_size(size, file_path)
        if not rr:
            print('\n***** No file(s) found *****\n')
        else:
            break

    except ValueError:
        print('\n***** Enter an numeric value. *****\n')
        continue
```

You can do

```
size = input('\nPlease enter file size: ')
while size.isdigit() == False or not rr = search_by_size(size, file_path):
    size = input('\nPlease enter file size: ')
```

## Your edited code: *Original: 59 lines*; *Edited: 33 lines*:

```
if os.path.exists(file_path)!= True:
    print('\n******* Path does not exist. *******\n')
else:
    while True:
        aa = '''\nWhich search characteristics would you like to use? \n 1. Search by name: N \n 2. Search by extension: E \n 3. Search by size: S
            \n    Please enter your choice: '''
        answer = input(aa).strip()
        if answer not in 'NnEeSs' or answer=='':
            print('\n***** Invalid choice. *****')
        elif answer.lower() == 'n':
            name = input ('\nEnter file name: ')
            try:
                while not search_by_name(name, file_path):
                    name = input ('\nEnter file name: ')
            except WindowsError:
                print('\n***** Oops! Access denied.*****\n')
                continue
        elif answer .lower() == 'e':
            ending = input ('\nEnter the file extension: ')
            try:
                while not search_by_extention(ending, file_path):
                    ending = input ('\nEnter the file extension: ')
            except WindowsError:
                print('\n***** Oops! Access denied. *****\n')
                continue
        elif answer.lower() == 's':
            size = input('\nPlease enter file size: ')
            try:
                while size.isdigit() == False or not search_by_size(size, file_path):
                    size = input('\nPlease enter file size: ')
            except WindowsError:
                print('\n***** Oops! Access denied. *****\n')
                continue
```